# Can snmp trap be faked?

Tags: snmp, snmp-trap, opennms

We had issues in faking traps by using validation traps for testing.

We have a scenario, where *alert trap* is followed by *clear trap* from a router to NMS mgr. These two traps have varbinds coming from **tabular objects** of MIB

Testing with validation traps is not really helping to test the real traps.

---

Can any snmp trap be faked using trap generators?

Comment: See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280356/sending-snmp2-trap-message-from-linux-command-lne

Answer (score 3):

Any good SNMP simulator can generate any trap you want in any sequence with any variable bindings to test your application.

Answer (score 3):

You can use on Linux the Net-SNMP utility `snmptrap`. It allows to send any kind of trap to your Trap receiver.

The following example sends a trap to destination 10.42.23.42 and adds a String with the content `just now!`. The SNMP version is `2c` and the community is set to `public`.

```
snmptrap -v 2c -c public 10.42.23.42 '' 1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.4.5.0.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.1.2.3.4 s 'just now!'"`
```

If you need to simulate also the senders IP address you can reuse this [simple script](https://github.com/opennms-forge/snmptrap-tester/blob/master/snmptrap-from.sh) which some of us use from time to time in our OpenNMS community to debug or simulate SNMP Traps.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the net-snmp util packages first via yum which would give you snmptrap command.
Make sure that your /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file has proper destination IP's and Community String set pointing towards the destination server and make sure that the Community String is defined the same on both.
Then restart snmpd service
Then go ahead and send the trap as belows
snmptrap -v 2c -c community-string host-ip/host-name

You would require the OID of the event that you are trying to simulate usually you can find them only or you could perform the snmpwalk command which i suppose would be the longer way around.